# Laravel override group middleware

Tags: php, laravel, throttling

How to override group middleware? What i want to achieve is to add other throttle limit for register/login routes.

My current throttle is set in kernel.

```
'api' => [
        'throttle:40,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
```

I want to set new throttle limit for login/register routes.

This is how i did it.

```
Route::post('login', 'Api\UserController@login')->middleware('throttle:15,3')->name('user.login');
Route::post('register', 'Api\UserController@register')->middleware('throttle:15,3')->name('user.register');
```

When i run php artisan route:list it says that this middleware api,throttle:15,3 is applied to this route.

The problem is when i run login request, response header says

```
X-RateLimit-Limit       40
X-RateLimit-Remaining   38
```

So as far as i see my new middleware is not applied. But my throttle requests are counted twice. How can i apply different middleware for throttle on login/register routes and override the old one ?

Answer (score 6):

Old topic, but its the first i found; time for an updated answer.

I've had this problem in the past as well. My solution back then was to add the middleware in the constructor of the controllers. I dislike it but it works.

I'm currently using Laravel 8 with a new project and found that the following solution works:

1. Set the default middleware in `kernel.php`

```
'api' => [
        'throttle:40,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
```

2. Remove the middleware `throttle:40,1` from the specific route, and add the correct middleware `throttle:15,3`:

```
Route::post('login', 'Api\UserController@login')->withoutMiddleware('throttle:40,1')->middleware('throttle:15,3')->name('user.login');
```

If you do not remove the middleware, it will run the throttle middleware twice per request.

I also played around with `$this->middleware( 'throttle:40,1' )->except( ['login'] )` in the constructor of `Api\UserController`, however that does not give the required result; it will just add the middleware for all but one method, it does not overwrite.

Comment: You dont have to change te kernel for the API. You can just say "->withoutMiddleware('throttle:api')"

Comment: If you have a rate limiter configured in the `RouseServiceProvider` for API, and have added `throttle:api` as middleware, then yes. But as far as I know, you need to remove the exact string of middleware that you added. Thus if you added `throttle:40,1` you cannot undo that by removing middleware `throttle:api`.

Comment: Correct. But the `throttle:api` is enabled by default when you create a new Laravel project.

Comment: You hopefully realise that you're commenting on a 4 year old topic, right? And the `throttle:api` has only been there since Laravel 8, while the topic relates to Laravel 5.1+

Answer (score 1):

Had this same question and just did some research. It doesn't appear that there is a way to overwrite the middleware configuration.

I, too, see that my middleware has updated in `route:list` but when resolving the middleware, it always uses a merged set of rules and so that initial `api` rule will end up overriding anything that defines something else over that.

You have a couple of options:

1. Remove the throttle rule from the Kernel `api` middleware definition and then use a `Route::group()` to re-add that specific rule to the rest of the routes. Then, in the same file, you can create a new `Route::group()` which defines the custom throttle config.

   ```
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'throttle:120,1'], function () {
        ...
   });

   Route::group(['middleware' => 'throttle:15,3'], function () {
        ...
   });
   ```
2. Create a custom `api-auth.php` file which is wrapped in a custom middleware group that you define just like the default `api` middleware. (You'll need to add another call in your `RouteServiceProvider` to load it like this:

   ```
   public function map() { 
       ...
       $this->mapCustomAuthRoutes();
   }

   protected function mapCustomAuthRoutes()
   {
       Route::middleware(['throttle:15,3', 'bindings'])
           ->namespace($this->namespace)
           ->as('api.')
           ->group(base_path('routes/api-auth.php'));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to override a group middleware is to disable it and then enable another one:

```php
Route::withoutMiddleware(ThrottleRequests::class.':api')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware(ThrottleRequests::class.':custom')->group(function () {
        ///
    });
});
```

Let me know if there's a better way to do it. I'd like to clean this up.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Throttle Middleware from the Global Group: In your **app/Http/Kernel.php** file, remove the Throttle Middleware from the global api group. The global group is applied to all routes by default.

Change this:

```
'api' => [
    'throttle:40,1',
    'bindings',
],
```

to this:

```
'api' => [
    'bindings',
],
```

Define a New Middleware Group: Create a new middleware group in your app/Http/Kernel.php file specifically for API throttling. You can give it a custom name like 'api.throttle'.

```
'api.throttle' => [
    'throttle:40,1', // The default throttle for most API routes
],
```

Apply the Custom Middleware Group to Most API Routes: Now, apply your new api.throttle middleware group to most of your API routes in your routes/api.php file. This will apply the default throttle to most routes.

```
Route::middleware(['api.throttle'])->group(function () {
    // Define your API routes here.
});
```

Override the Middleware on Login/Register Routes: For the login and register routes, you can override the api.throttle middleware with your custom throttle settings.

```
Route::post('login', 'Api\UserController@login')->middleware('throttle:15,3')->name('user.login');
Route::post('register', 'Api\UserController@register')->middleware('throttle:15,3')->name('user.register');
```

This is just an idea and the approach which I use most.

**OR**
You can create a new call like below.

Define a new middleware group in the **App\Http\Kernel.php** file. For example, let's call it throttle-auth:

```
'throttle-auth' => 'throttle:15,3',
```

Apply like below.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'throttle-auth'], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'Api\UserController@login')->name('user.login');
    Route::post('register', 'Api\UserController@register')->name('user.register');
});
```